# Rollback a delete operation using transaction logs

Tags: sql-server, rollback, transaction-log

Need to roll back a delete operation from the transaction logs in sql server 2008 but unsure how to do this.

Can anyone give me a point in the right direction for the correct syntax for this operation??

I'd be very grateful,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this using MS provided tools in SQL. Apex has a log utility http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.asp will likely sort your issue. If you can't get that then restoring is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

the only supported way is to restore from backup.
if you want to go crazy you can do something like [this](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/10/12/sql-server-ndash-undelete-a-table-and-restore-a-single.aspx)

but i'd suggest you take a backup before attempting anything like that.